# Unable to take dump using mongodump

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-atlas, atlas

I have an atlas mongoDB and i have connected to the database through mongoshell using below the command.

```bash
mongosh “mongodb+srv://hostname.mongodb.net/?authSource=%24external&authMechanism=MONGODB-X509&retryWrites=true&w=majority” --tls --tlsCertificateKeyFile x5091248.pem
```

But i am unable to take database dump using `mongodump` command can someone share me the `mongodump` command for above scenario.

Comment: What `mongodump` commands have you tried and what happened with each?

Answer (score 0):

Try to put all into the connection string. i.e

```
mongodb+srv://hostname.mongodb.net/?authSource=$external&authMechanism=MONGODB-X509&tls=true&tlsCertificateKeyFile=x5091248.pem
```

You may also add parameter for CA-File like `tlsCAFile=/etc/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt`

I think `retryWrites` and `w` are not relevant for a dump.